# VB.NET - Public Variable does not hold value between functions

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF Service in VB.NET. My current situation is that I want to keep a variable saying true or false if the user is or is not logged!

Code:

```
Public Property User_Logged As Boolean
Public Function Login(ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean Implements SQLOperator.Login
    ...
    If (Username = "root" and Password="test") Then
     User_Logged = True
     MsgBox(User_Logged)
    Else
     User_Logged = False
     MsgBox(User_Logged)
    End If
End Function

Public Function UserIsLogged() As Boolean Implements SQLOperator.UserIsLogged
    MsgBox("islogged: " & User_Logged)
End Function
```

In the second function, the variable output is false and in the first function it outputed true.

Comment: There is no concept of a variable "not holding" its value. If the value changes it is because it was changed or because you're dealing with a different instance of the containing class.

Comment: I must agree with Enigmativity. If that's the case you could try making the variable `Public Shared`.

Comment: That's why I post this question. I have no idea what's going on. I posted the code.

Comment: ...`why do you have functions that do not return anything`? Turn `Option Strict On`...